# How can I create this mapped type to reduce the input to the desired shape?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have the following `State` shape and want to define a flattened `slice` const that has the types of the state properties without needing to explicitly define/reference them again, so I would like a mapped type like `MapFlatSlice`:

```
type State = {
  fruit: {
    mango: 'haden' | 'keitt';
    papaya: 'sunrise' | 'strawberry';
  };
  colors: {
    green: 10 | 20 | 30;
  };
  season: {
    nartana: 'april' | 'may' | 'june' | 'july' | 'august';
  };
};

type MapFlatSlice = {
  // ...
};

const slice = {
  fruit: ['mango', 'papaya'],
  colors: ['green'],
  season: ['nartana'],
} as const;

type S = MapFlatSlice<typeof slice>;
```

Where `S` should be:

```
type S = {
  mango: 'haden' | 'keitt';
  papaya: 'sunrise' | 'strawberry';
  green: 10 | 20 | 30;
  nartana: 'april' | 'may' | 'june' | 'july' | 'august';
};
```

In the above example, `slice` is used for something like redux's `mapStateToProps`, like this:

```
const makeSlice = (s: Slice): (t: MapFlatSlice<typeof s>) => void => {
  // ...
};
```

So given:

```
const s1 = makeSlice(slice);
```

Then `s1` would be:

```
const s1 = (props: {
  mango: "haden" | "keitt";
  papaya: "sunrise" | "strawberry";
  green: 10 | 20 | 30;
  nartana: "april" | "may" | "june" | "july" | "august";
}) => {};
```

(where the type of `props` in `s1` is the same as `S` from above)

---

So I think that `MapFlatSlice` should be something like...

```
type MapFlatSlice<S extends { [k in keyof State]?: readonly (keyof State[k])[] }> = {
  [k in keyof S]: {
    [_k in S[k][number]]: ...
  };
};
```

But I don't know how to "flatten" it, and also it doesn't work to index `S[k]` with `number`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you asking to extract the types from `State` like this [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nn6oqN), or some object literal `const extract`, or was that just something you were attempting along the way?

Comment: @chrisbajorin Thanks for your help. In the question I renamed "Extract" instances to "Slice" since that is already a utility type. As for your question, the `const slice` is passed to a function that returns a function that accepts the return type of MapFlatSlice<typeof slice>. It's similar to redux mapStateToProps. I have added more details to the question to hpefully clarify what I am trying to do.

Comment: Is `slice` meant to be selecting a subset of the existing properties? That is, is `const slice = {fruit: ['mango'], color: ['green'], season: [] } as const;` meant as a potential/intended input to the type?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm hoping to accomplish, `const slice = ...` is meant as an input to the type

Comment: Uh, is `State` supposed to have `colors` or `color` as a key?  Is this a typo?  If so, could you fix it?  If not, could you explain what's going on with the discrepancy?

Comment: @jcalz sorry yes, typo. Fixed and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to approach this as follows:

---

Which types are "sliceable"?  That is, when you write `MapFlatSlice<T>`, what are the allowable types for `T`?  I think it's any type `T extends Sliceable<T>` where `Sliceable<T>` is defined as:

```
type Sliceable<T> =
  { [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof State ? ReadonlyArray<keyof State[K]> : never }
```

That is, if `T` is sliceable, each property at key `K` must be a (possibly read-only) array of keys of `State[K]`.  If `K` is not a key of `State`, then there should be no property at key `K` (so the property is of type `never`).

---

Now that we've got a constraint on the input to `MapFlatSlice`, what should the output be?  I find this easiest to break into two steps.  We will take the input type `T` and "invert" the keys and values, to give us something closer to the shape of what we want which still has enough information in it to get the job done.

Here it is:

```
type InvertKeyValues<T extends Record<keyof T, readonly PropertyKey[]>> =
  { [K in keyof T as T[K][number]]: K };
```

If we apply that directly to `typeof slice`, you'll see what we get:

```
type Intermediate = InvertKeyValues<typeof slice>;    
/* type Intermediate = {
    readonly mango: "fruit";
    readonly papaya: "fruit";
    readonly green: "color";
    readonly nartana: "season";
} */
```

The keys are the ones you want in your final output, and the values are the relevant keys from `State` we need to consult.

---

Given such an intermediate type as a new input `U`, we can do the final transformation:

```
type DoSlice<U> =
  { -readonly [K in keyof U]: Idx<Idx<State, U[K]>, K> }
```

Recall that `U[K]` is the key from `State`, while `K` is the subkey.  So we want to write `State[U[K]][K]`.  But the compiler can't tell that such index accesses are valid, so we use `Idx<O, P>` in place of `O[P]`, which we define now:

---

Let's say we have an object type `O` and a key type `P`, but the compiler doesn't know that `P` is a key of `O` even though we think it is.  That means we can't directly write the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `O[P]` without error.  Instead, we can define an `Idx` type alias which checks `P` before indexing:

```
type Idx<O, P> = P extends keyof O ? O[P] : never;
```

Now, anywhere `O[P]` yields an error, we can replace it with `Idx<O, P>`.  And so inside `DoSlice`, `State[U[K]][K]` becomes `Idx<Idx<State, U[K]>, K>`.

---

And finally, `MapFlatSlice<T>` is defined in terms of the constraint and the output operation:

```
type MapFlatSlice<T extends Sliceable<T>> =
  DoSlice<InvertKeyValues<T>>
```

---

So, does it work?

```
type S = MapFlatSlice<typeof slice>
/* type S = {
    mango: "haden" | "keitt";
    papaya: "sunrise" | "strawberry";
    green: 10 | 20 | 30;
    nartana: "april" | "may" | "june" | "july" | "august";
} */
```

Looks good.  You can verify that other mappings should also work, and that adding incorrect properties to `slice` should result in compiler warnings.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8CwAoKUBmATgK4CWwAXOtrrgLbwB2A5gPaUDkAFvACYQPsoAHyjsA1hDLB2Abmo0w8RSHgcAzkQYESaiIJHs1wAvADuAIwgECIWfIC+cnFADGLADYsClTM9xMCCH5KAEYABmEoACYIkQBmMKdcR3ldeDUWBh95XAZ4AgQ8jiVtd31ReltI9gArTT1quvcqg3giJiIjO2cUrF7sUEhYdxIXCHhzdwgAHgAVAD4oZHk0KABtAGkoEgYoCRAWPChZgF1KLYgADyQGHjU9iAOjuERoAH4oACVxnkzmgEFrPAQNN9odYAgkJsTotKAwIAA3KxQezYAbgaAASQYSIKG0eADV4O4iBA1HMoFcbncvhA3AQeKDHuDZgAaKCBXh-EBQAAKBBYkAKIHxIDWMMWy2cq02212YKOsyg6WO0LWDCItEsBBOZygW36WEGWJ4l2mAHl2bzJXzKdd+DSFVBzVAPua1ryTlA4YirE50UMACIsGAjMbTACqkpWUAAtJzfgxmustjsHk8oBG9ZjTdMc2aXkh2RHofN2RtFqisAHoABZJQAMXciFDoxmSqpDvurbGEymc3m0ecwZ7M2xuOAoqJJLJA-maKwbgYRigajDKCozkIpAo63Y9GYLHY7PYimU8HYJ1Z8jcnm8e4CQQEV9S4wyWT3eQKjAvL76yvuJcjH9I0MVgJYoHrMAmxbddpmNcE1zbecsAAegAKigY1wNQXwaCgA9WEoAAibg+AYYjImIiQpGIpIFCUYFVCgYiNC0HQIEokRWOMMxtRsOicigR9gigcJIhiSIEno3J8kKZjiJKEh3C4ljKlU4i6nhDSmhADS2g6IxBP-dDUIXczq0shdsOxJACFoCAeBIV4IPHKxJ0JYlSXJBCjiQsZ5hAjCsLA2yrAcpyXNwoSE25AjGCIljtzIYz8NipMeTPJiSOS4BUpodLkxEj9iNvLx8twQqeS-eSSLSd9jPsKBTIsoA)

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and for the detailed explanation around the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using a utility type `ArrayType` to extract the keys from your `const slice` arrays:

```
type ArrayType<T extends readonly any[] | undefined> = 
  T extends readonly (infer V)[] ? V : never;
```

You can extract all the nested objects into a union using:

```
// Extract a union of the nested object properties
// State -> { mango: ...; papaya: ...; } | { green: ...; } | { nartana: ...; }
type GetNestedProps<State, Slice extends {[K in keyof State]?: readonly (keyof State[K])[]}> = {
    [K in keyof Slice]: K extends keyof State 
                     // ^ This typeguard lets us use `K` to index `State` in `Pick`
                     // where we'll select only the keys passed in by the `slice` object
        ? Pick<State[K], (ArrayType<Slice[K]> extends keyof State[K] ? ArrayType<Slice[K]> : never)> 
        //                                    ^ this is a necessary typeguard to make sure we can use the
        //                                      return of ArrayType<Slice[K]> as an index on State[K]
        : never
}[keyof Slice];
// ^ indexing with the keyof, we get a union of the values on the object
```

Any time you want to index with a key that wasn't extracted from the object, you need to use a typeguard to assure the compiler that the key can be used as an index on your object. If you notice, I made the keys optional in the type parameter. This will allow you to exclude the keys in your `const slice` instead of having an empty array. If you prefer to force empty arrays, you can remove the questions marks from `[K in keyof State]?`.

Now that you have a union of the nested properties, you can use the utility type `UnionToIntersection` to convert that to your desired type:

```
// X | Y -> X & Y
type UnionToIntersection<T> = 
  (T extends any ? (x: T) => any : never) extends 
  (x: infer R) => any ? R : never;
```

Finally, your actual type, where I added `State` as a type parameter to make it reusable across states:

```
type MapFlatSlice<State,Slice extends {[K in keyof State]?: readonly (keyof State[K])[]}> = 
  UnionToIntersection<GetNestedProps<State,Slice>>;
```

useable as:

```
const slice = {
  fruit: ['mango','papaya'],
  color: ['green'],
  season: ['nartana'],
} as const;

type S = MapFlatSlice<State,typeof slice>;

const s: S = {
    mango: 'haden',
    papaya: 'sunrise',
    green: 10,
    nartana: 'april'
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8CwAoKUBmATgK4CWwAXOtrrgLbwB2A5gPaUDkAFvACYQPsoAHyjsA1hDLB2Abmo0w8RSHgcAzkQYESaiIJHs1wAvADuAIwgECIWfIC+cnFADGLADYsClTM9xMCCH5KAEYABmEoACYIkQBmMKdcR3ldeDUWBh95XAZ4AgQ8jiVtd31ReltI9gArTT1quvcqg3giJiIjO2cUrF7sAHoBqAANSIBNKABaAD5RqAAyKHHsUEgoAFUGEkyAFRYASQYkAl0XYB2GAB5dudR5AApdqAgADyQGHjUoRhAoAH4oA9XpRdgBKKDIOa-KCUBgQABuVghbw+XygjxBUBIDDwVigACUIVCfgw-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-yg2TPhXgC0TgrjfyaO5MR-JyaykpoWzTHZQIoFMPRvSgXRPKPaTL0EmMoEUNRdE9ONzD+Ir-M5bkIGCu8H3ORLNMBWKXDEJiFIgJSdQeGsTDrBs2IapS5mM75TNEpTVyGu160gJj2Im9dEWROY2pS4Zkr2-bLIctlnOc+BqUfT81HyGrXKIdyQvoCRcqIDKstcRhfOgS9ttwWyDv+g7AmAF6GHPKAFpG5axp5Nb0gLHEwozUHZt4o0fvW2lsHsJUZv0pxbIchG3jzTKyE4eNiszHU3qYMjj1PTIwaKhF4HDT8kYp5rH2AbAiOgABZJQADF3EQaGIB638tXFptx24viBJm3rxMktMpwYDsHiV38lJUtTIU2bY9kOY4rDOC5MiuUiKKoj06NfRjROl9iZhmeksDcFNgFy9iDY0-BiDISglXYICWHYLV2AglR2CNLV5DcTxvGVdhkP4WP4+cNIMlQkOcMKeAM6xn5vk9ox3bWaAYANwWwBFsX2MlljK7k+qeTd3mPclb21EoavUH9ugLTYURuD4ARM806OoMMTRtF0CPErT1Dwknmh87w4pnxIMosc7sue-YqI-cSwhSAoZVzQ1Y1i7hg+K8rWBj9QWv6+AcWm4gHUW6zNuICiDuXcva5SiH3Z+VA-CAWHhwMe6c947iwAMAAVEg6gSCoC7gJASAA8pSXYu4YC7BgGggY+9u65TiH3E+kCw4wN4OnNeuBp7qDnjoPQjCoC2QAAKCimG8SA5w+HWC8IlBgLBgBVl4kJDgi9IHL1CGEDhG8iiiBKDvdg8DO7YAPj7BqcRqGaTPkHFOYcI6iGnmY9gLAHax00Yg4YPC1B8NeAI4AQiXwED5rAfRL9hai3fo3J2LlICt3YnEGYZDgF-wACwGJoEYi+IdTGRwsXHRKicvDB1ToEdOaTIHZ0yFk5Rhc8maQuLQCAWTjrMDULYvoMpHHONce4kRWBK6wFib4uu-iP5BJ-ronk0SIkIOwEAA)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help with this! Great to see another approach to this, and thank you for the explanation.